# preg_grep does not return the right results

Tags: php, preg-grep

The following code does not capture 45.00 as a result:

```
$array = array(50,45.00,34,56,6.67);
$fl_array = preg_grep("/^(\d+)?\.(\d)+$/", $array);
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: What is your accepted output ?

Comment: only the floating numbers

Comment: Try `"/^(\d+)?[\.(\d)+]?$/"`

Answer (score 1):

If you do a `var_dump($array);` you will get:

```
array(5) {
  [0]=> int(50)
  [1]=> float(45)
  [2]=> int(34)
  [3]=> int(56)
  [4]=> float(6.67)
}
```

PHP you transform `45.00` into `45`. That's why you can't find with the regex.

What you can do is to insert only strings.

```
$array = array("50","45.00","34","56","6.67");
```

Then it's going to work.

Another option is to filter only float numbers from the array:

```
$array = array(50,45.00,34,56,6.67);
$fl_array = array_filter($array, function($item) {
    return is_float($item);
});
```